# Ionic Serve- XMLHttpRequest cannot load on Browser

Tags: javascript, api, ionic-framework

I am currently writing a feature in the Ionic framework that requires communication with an API. I attempt to use the `XMLHttpRequest()` function like the majority of resources I found online call for, but the request fails each time, despite the fact that I have internet access, with the `cannot load` error.

If it makes any difference, I am testing the app with `ionic serve --lab`, and through a local machine (which is connected to the internet. I guess I am also wondering to some degree what the proper way to communicate with a RESTful API through Ionic would be, as well. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: could you share the error screenshot?

Comment: machine can't currently screenshot, but I'll definitely include it in the morning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is CORS. While you are in your app your mobile phone handles the cross domain connections for you but in your browser its a no go.

What you need to do is setup a proxy using your ionic.project

```
{
  "name": "appName",
  "app_id": "",
    "proxies": [
    {
      "path": "/devapi",
      "proxyUrl": "https://api.somewebsite.com/api/"
    }
  ]
}
```

After this every ajax request you do should be simply sent to "/devapi"
This is what I did to not switch every 5 seconds between them in my application initlization

```
if (window.cordova) {
  $rootScope.baseURL = 'https://api.somewebsite.com/api/';
} else {
  $rootScope.baseURL = 'devapi/';
}
```

Further reading about proxies: http://ionicinaction.com/blog/how-to-fix-cors-issues-revisited/

Comment: I believe you are absolutely correct in that this is the problem. Think you could elaborate what exactly the /devapi path is? Is it a local directory?

Comment: Its like a virtual path. Everytime devapi is in the url its transformed by ionic to the webserver api url. I added a link that explains in depth

Comment: Hm. I changed the given information, and on my browser, when I navigate to 'localhost:8100/api/', it redirects me to the proper url with the proper information! However, the network call still fails and returns null..

Comment: Did you change the urls you are calling in the ajax calls?

Comment: Indeed. I believe the error lies somewhere else at this point, so I'll accept your answer for pointing me in the right direction. Thank you!